# matrix is not printed well, when being accesses by threads

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix

i want to increase +1 the numbers inside a row of matrix using threads.

- two threads can't access at the same row at the same time
- two thread can access to different rows at the same time

what i wrote is that (***only the shared resource method***):

```
public void increaseRow(Integer row) {
        if (!mapForRow.containsKey(row))
            mapForRow.put(row, "not increased");
        if (mapForRow.get(row).equals("not increased")) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                while (rowIncreased) {
                    condition.await();
                }
                mapForRow.get(row).equals("increased");
                rowIncreased = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
                    setMatrix(row, j, matrix[row][j] + 1);
                rowIncreased = false;
                // replace the value
                mapForRow.get(row).equals(" not increased");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("begin print matrix");
                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    System.out.println();
                    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("end print matrix ");
                System.out.println();
                lock.unlock();
                condition.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

***the matrix is initialized with 10 rows and 10 columns and the threads started are also 10***

but via output i' m getting this:

```
begin print matrix

0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
end print matrix 


begin print matrix

00Exception in thread "Thread-0" 00000000
0000000000
0000000000
end print matrix 

java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
[...]
```

i can understand the the thrown exception, but why the matrix is not fully displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use an `AtomicInteger` for that. These can be safely accessed and manipulated from multiple threads without the need of locking.

If you imagine your code as in between the lines starting with `//`, you can see that, the `NullPointerException` will be caught and handled while the lock is in place, but if any other exception is thrown, one that is not caught in that block, the exception will progress up the stack trace until caught, and when it is caught, you lock will long have been released.

```
try {

  // start of your code
  lock.lock();
  try {
    doStuff();
  } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("in lock");
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }

  // end of your code

} catch(Exception e) { // IllegalMonitorStateException caught here
  System.out.println("not in lock");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll try that. But can you explain me why the threads interrupt their print?

Comment: That exception seems to have been caught by an uncaught exception handler, not by your exception handler in your code block. As such the lock will have been released by your finally block by then

Comment: it is not a nullPointException, but IllegalMonitorStateException , and if you see the lock and unlock is inside a try - catch- finally block.